# GWT - internationalization of entity properties

Tags: gwt, internationalization, entity

I'm looking for an elegant solution for the following problem:

In my database, I have some predefined(!) entities. These entities have names and descriptions (Strings). Around the data access layer, there are some EJBs containing business logic to load/search for/etc. those entities.

Now for the frontend, we are developing a GWT application which calls the EJB methods on our backend.

The problem is, that the name and the descriptions of the entities mentioned above must be internationalized - e.g., depending on the user's locale, an entity's description must be "My cool description" (English) or "Beschreibung bla" (German) or whatever :)

My first approach was to use a resource string in the database. So entity A has a description "descriptionA", entity B has a description "descriptionB"... Later on, the GWT app (or any other client) translates this resource string into the actual description using some kind of "resource bundle". E.g.:

*resources_en.properties*:

descriptionA=Actual Description of Entity A

descriptionB=Actual Description of Entity B

*resources_de.properties*:

descriptionA=Beschreibung A

descriptionB=Beschreibung B

(Remember, the entities are predefined, so it's possible to "know" all descriptions at compile time. BUT it would be better if the resource bundle could be enhanced without having to recompile the application).

Is this possible with GWT? How can I do this? Is it better to "translate" on the server or on the client side?

Otherwise, I've to deal with all that i18n stuff on the backend side. Well, this would allow to keep data together (instead of defining the descriptions on the client side). But the big drawback is that the backend must be aware of the caller's locale.

Regards,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly a decision between download time/speed vs flexibility. If you compile it GWT inlines the messages and can generate a little faster code, because no string lookup has to be done. However, if you need to make changes and don't want to recompile or want to be a able to let users dynamically alter messages you need dynamic messages.

Regarding the latter case, the [Dictionary](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Dictionary.html) class can help you with this, see also: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html#DevGuideDynamicStringInternationalization
With the Dictionary you generate all messages in the static page served to the user. The users locale can be found in the header [Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4), which is send by the browser when a page is requested.

In either case (compiled or dynamic) you might want to serve the locale set by the user in some configuration property and in that case you still need logic for both cases on the server side to serve the locale to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible for those who try...

Back to your question: there are several ways to resolve your issue. One would be to introduce some kind of i18n facade and treat your descriptions and names as resource keys. Then you could define convenience methods to access translations i.e. `public String translate(String message, Locale locale);`. This method could use standard Java ResourceBundle class to access resources at runtime.

The only real problem I see is how to deal with compound messages (i.e. "Blah, blah 4 items" where 4 is a placeholder). Well, what we did in one project in similar situation, we added delimiter and actual resource key then another delimiter and count: "Blah, blah 4 items##items.in.your.whatever##4". In the case of English you could simply trim the first part and for other languages you would need to process whole string.